# mysql, prepared statements, and automatic type conversion

Tags: mysql, types, type-conversion, prepared-statement

I am getting different results performing the exact same query using regular statements and prepared statements, and I think it's a type conversion bug.

```
mysql> show columns from server where field = "vlan";
+-------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| vlan        | int(5) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> select hostname from server where `vlan` = '184.182' limit 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> prepare stupid from "select hostname from server where `vlan` = ? limit 1";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> set @vlan = '184.182';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> execute stupid using @vlan;
+-------------------+
| hostname          |
+-------------------+
| web20.servers.com |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

the real value of `vlan` is `184`

it looks like the way mysql is handling type conversions is different for prepared statements and regular statements? does that make sense? how do i fix this?

Comment: What if you perform `where vlan = '184.182'`?

Comment: as mentioned, in this case nothing comes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected data type of prepared statement parameters is determined upon statement preparation, and type conversion to that data type takes place prior to statement execution.

In your example, an integer parameter is expected; therefore the provided string is cast to an integer (184) before the statement is executed, and the comparison between the integer column `vlan` and the parameter is successful for the matching record.

The "regular" statement, by contrast, compares the integer column with a string; therefore the arguments are compared as floating point numbers, and no record has a matching `vlan`.

To avoid this situation, ensure that the data type cannot be determined upon preparation (or that the determined data type does not lose any information) - for example:

```
prepare not_so_stupid from
  "select hostname from server where `vlan` = CAST(? AS CHAR) limit 1"
;
```